# Android ~ Decoupling Drawn Objects from GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android but in all tutorials I see people creating FloatBuffers and Textures inside the Renderer itself (or the onSurfaceCreate() method).

Personally I think it's really ugly that all those things have to be in the Renderer class. I'd rather have a method Draw(Sprite sprite) in the GLSurfaceView.Renderer such that the Sprite holds the Texture and the vertex data. I just don't really know how this is possible and how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea(or references) for a Sprite class which could be easily passed to the Renderer and be drawn?

Thanks a lot,

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this. One would be having a sprite interface that you then create concrete classes with your sprite objects. In that interface you would just need a method to get the texture.

```
public interface Sprite {
   public void createTexture();

   public int getTexture();
}

public class MySprite implements Sprite {
    private int[] spriteTexture = int[1];

    public void createTexture() {
       GLES20.glGenTextures(1, spriteTexture, 0);
       GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture[0]);
       //Set your texture params
       //Set your image to the texture
    }

    public int getTexture() {
      return spriteTexture[0];
    }
}
```

Then your drawing code in the renderer you just access the sprite you want.

```
//Setup program to draw with
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mySprite.getTexture());
//Rest of rendering code
```

The other option would be to put all the drawing code in the Sprite class but since most of it will be the same between Sprite you could end with duplicate code, of course one way to resolve that would be to have an abstract BaseSprite class that handles most of the drawing calls and accesses the texture of the Sprite.

Your GLES20 calls can live pretty much anywhere in the code the only important thing to consider/remember is that your opengl context needs to be created before you call them, and they need to be called from the same thread, because each thread gets it's own context.

Comment: You're my hero man:P This really helps me a lot! Just as one last question! Could I also put my FloatBuffers in that Sprite class or do you think that is a bad idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Yea you could definitely put them in that class. As a matter of cleanness you may want to consider a rectangle glass that constructs the rectangle and creates the float buffer. That way you could also possibly use for other things like the background. But that would be up to you want to structure your code.